# html2text result deletes some special caracters

Tags: php

I am trying to display a message using html2text function, the result in encoded in utf-8, the only problem is that for some cases, caracters are deleted from the words.

Example: instead of **n'hésitez** I get **nhsitez**, here is my code

```
$h2t = new html2text($leMessage);
$altBody = $h2t->get_text();
logMessagePreformate($id_dossier, utf8_decode($sujet),$altBody, $pour1, $pour2);
```

I tried to utf8_encode and mb_convert_encoding but it didn't work, any suggestions ?

Comment: Can you give us an example of a string you're having issues with?

Comment: where is le message coming from? is your php file, html meta tag, db tables and fields, everything, utf-8? utf-8 all the things!

Comment: all stings with é caracters, it displays them without é example : **journée = journee**
le message comes from a file that is encoded in utf-8

Comment: Which html2text library are you using? There are several and perhaps you are not using an updated and supported one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who face the same problem, I added **html_entity_decode()** function to my code in order to decode the data I send to the database :

```
$h2t = new html2text(html_entity_decode($leMessage));
```

then to display it I used:

`mb_convert_encoding($h2t),"HTML-ENTITIES", 'UTF-8')`